# Increase efficiency of basic string compressor

Tags: python, strings, compression

I was wondering what I can do to increase the performance of this program. The algorithm is pretty slow right now but I was wondering what I can do to increase the efficiency of this program.  I used lists instead of strings to avoid immutable string concatenation.

This program should compress strings by the number of characters within the string

Example:

```
aaabbbcc --> a3b3c2
```

Code:

```
def compressBad(string):
    string = list(string)
    mystr = []
    last = string[0]
    count = 1
    for x in xrange(1,len(string)):
        if string[x] == last:
            count += 1
        else:
            mystr.append(last)
            mystr.append(str(count))
            last = string[x]
            count = 1
    # add the last character
    mystr.append(last)
    mystr.append(str(count))
    return ''.join(mystr)

print compressBad("abaabccc")
```

output:

```
a1b1a2b1c3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code performs twice as fast as your code does on my machine, both for short strings (e.g. your example) and longer strings.

```
def compressBetter(string):
    last = string[0]
    result = []
    count = 1
    for c in string[1:]:
        if c == last:
            count += 1
        else:
            result.append(last + `count`)
            count = 1
            last = c

    result.append(last + `count`)
    return ''.join(result)
```

The main two optimisations are

1. Using backticks instead of `str()` for `int` to `str` conversion (note that backticks are deprecated and have been removed in Python 3). Some discussion of why they are faster is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-num).
2. Iterating over the string directly rather than indexing. I'm guessing this saves function calls, which have quite a lot of overhead in python.

I find that each optimisation accounts for about half of the performance increase. I am using cPython - the results would probably be very different if you used a different interpreter.

Comment: would appending twice instead of result.append(last + `count`) lead to better results? No string concatenation?

Comment: I checked that and found no difference in performance (maybe because the strings are so short?). I used concatenation as it's more readable.

Comment: makes sense! thanks for your help! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Bugs:

- This currently crashes when the string is empty. It should either check for that, or (better) avoid treating the first character specially.
- When there's a run of more than 9 characters, the output is ill-formed: `rleCompress('aaaaaaaaaa')` ⇒ `'a10'`. You could avoid this by limiting runs to length 9, giving `'a9a1'` instead.

Simplifications and optimizations:

- There's no need to convert the string to a list. You can subscript strings too.
- The only thing you do with `x` is `string[x]`, so the loop can be simplified to `for c in string[1:]:`, or just `for c in string:` if you don't treat the first character specially.
- It might be faster to collect the output in a buffer rather than a list of strings, but Python doesn't have a good way to do this. You could try `StringIO`, but probably isn't significantly faster.

Names:

- This compression scheme is called [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), so the function's name should indicate that: `rleCompress`? `compressRuns`?
- `mystr` is the compressed result, so it should be called something like `compressed`.

You should probably write `rleDecompress` too, so you can use them to test each other:

```
assert rleDecompress(rleCompress(x)) == x
```